# Rational solutions to Catalan's equation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Famous Catalan's conjecture, now a theorem proved by Mihăilescu, states that the only solution in the natural numbers of the equation
$$
x^{a}-y^{b}=1.
$$
for $a, b > 1$ and $x, y > 0$ is $x = 3, a = 2, y = 2, b = 3$.

Is there any systematic research about rational solutions in $(x,y)$ to the same equation, where $a, b > 1$ are integers such that $(a,b)\neq (2,2)$? If $\text{gcd}(a,b)\geq 3$, then there are no solutions by Fermat Last Theorem. Cases $(a,b)=(2,3),(3,2),(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ correspond to elliptic curves and can be solved by standard methods. What are other solved cases? Are there any known rational solutions at all, other than ones with $xy=0$ and $(x,y)=(\pm 3,2)$ for $(a,b)=(2,3)$?

Comment: I now found an arXiv preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702766 that finds some  conditions on the exponents (a, b) for which the equation has no non-trivial rational solutions (Theorem 5).

Comment: I think that showing more than $\gcd(ab,6)=1$ is probably hard.